# How to get audio jack to work?

Tags: sound

So I have been hovering around the internet for the last couple of hours trying to figure out how to get my audio from my jack working. I have an alienware mx14 r3 with a sound blaster card. What is wierd is the speakers on my laptop will work but the jack will not. The reason why I am asking this question is because I have found conflicting solutions pretty much all around the web all of them not working. Of course I am running ubuntu 14.04 . I would love to head a clear and concise answer that is mildly understandable. I have run through alot of alsa commands on other website none of them working I made a couple changes to one alsa file to try to make it work but nothing happened (very anticlimactic). On a side note I am a little bit of a linux noob but I already love it I am duel booting a windows 7 laptop which runs the jack fine in windows.

Comment: I feel bad for doing this but the problem is still there so...